# How can I call didSendBodyData method and how to update on progress bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, request

1. How can I send byte data to another viewcontroller and use it on progressbar?
2. How can I upload video and set progressbarview as per indexpathrow which I selected?

Here is my code:

```
-(void)updateUserVideoResponse:(NSMutableDictionary*)params ImageFile:(NSData*)Img Completion:(void (^)(NSData *data,
NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))callback;

{   
    NSLog(@"Params %@",params);


    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",VideoAddResponseUrl,[params objectForKey:@"id"]]];


    // NSString *accessToken=[[AccessToken classMethodeOfAccessToken] getAccessToken];

    // NSData *webData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageProfile,0.5);


    NSLog(@"%.2f",(float)Img.length);


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:myURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

    NSString *boundary = @"_187934598797439873422234";

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];


    //  NSString *contentType = @"application/json";

    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@.mov\"\r\n",[params objectForKey:@"question"],[params objectForKey:@"question"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:Img]];

    // [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video-size\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",(float)Img.length] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"camera_resolution\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"AVCaptureSessionPresetLow"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSLog(@"Request body %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:callback] resume];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
   didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten
 totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite    {

    float progress = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesWritten] floatValue];
    float total = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger: totalBytesExpectedToWrite] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"progress/total %f",progress/total);
}
```

Comment: Your `didSendBodyData` is the deprecated `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` method. I believe you want [`URLSession:task:didSendBodyData:totalBytesSent:totalBytesExpectedToSend:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiontaskdelegate/1408299-urlsession?language=objc). And to do that, you cannot use `[NSURLSession sharedSession]`, but instead have to instantiate your own `NSURLSession` and specify a delegate for that. FYI, if uploading a large asset, I'd personally use an upload task, not a data task.

Comment: will you please share any stuff of code.